# Combination of n numbers into two unique groups

Tags: javascript, logic, permutation

I have to implement combination for a game where players are randomly selected into two group from n players in javascript.

For example:

If there are four players - A B C D

AB vs CD - first round team
AC vs BD - second round team
AD vs BC - third round team

If there are six players - A B C D E F

ABC vs DEF
ADE vs BCF

Each time a player is playing with unique player in such a way that no two players can play the game with same players three times in a row. Is there any way to generate such kind of combination.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its Easy to Archiv you can make a function where you simply pass in your 4 or 6 names as argument or better as array then simply random mix this array

The de-facto unbiased shuffle algorithm is the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle.

See https://github.com/coolaj86/knuth-shuffle

You can see a [great visualization here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) (and the original post [linked to this](http://sedition.com/perl/javascript-fy.html))

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length
    , temporaryValue
    , randomIndex
    ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Used like so

```
var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Some more info [about the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates%5fshuffle) used.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I will check them now.